# How to setup Nodejs environment for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Google Cloud Platform , I am following this tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs

After setting environment variables I used Google Cloud, this line is causing problem

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

when i comment out this line it works otherwise it throws an error

```
TypeError: Expected `input` to be a `Function` or `Object`, got `undefined`
push../node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/pify/index.js.module.exports
D:/SE/Web/React/storybook/node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/pify/index.js:56
53 | var objType = typeof input;
54 | 
55 | if (!(input !== null && (objType === 'object' || objType === 
'function'))) {
> 56 |   throw new TypeError("Expected `input` to be a `Function` or 
`Object`, got `".concat(input === null ? 'null' : objType, "`"));
 | ^  57 | }
 58 | 
 59 | var filter = function filter(key) {
 View compiled
 ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
 D:/SE/Web/React/storybook/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:65
 62 | 
 63 | var pify = require("pify");
 64 | 
 > 65 | var readFile = pify(fs.readFile);
 66 | var GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
 67 | var GOOGLE_REVOKE_TOKEN_URL = 
'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=';
 68 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the same tutorial as you mention above. It worked for me. Please make sure that you didn't skip any step in the process.

1. It is very important to [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) and download
   the JSON file to your computer. Then upload the JSON file in your
   Cloud Shell.
2. Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable in Cloud Shell to the path of the JSON file. Follow the instructions on [Setting the environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable).
3. Create a `Virtual Environment`. Execute `virtualenv [ENVIRONMENT_NAME]`.
4. Activate the environment by executing `source [ENVIRONMENT_NAME]/bin/activate`.
5. Install the `@google-cloud/storage` library. Execute `npm install --save @google-cloud/storage`.
6. Create a `Nodejs` file. Add the code form [Getting Started with Authentication > Verifying authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) documentation.
7. Run the file by executing `node [FILE_NAME].js`.

If your get an error:

> Error: [GSERVICEACCOUNT] does not have storage.buckets.list access to project [PROJECT_NUMBER].

1. Then copy the entire `[GSERVICEACCOUNT]`.
2. Go to you `Google Cloud Console`.
3. Go to `IAM & admin` page from navigation menu.
4. Click on `Add+`.
5. In `New members` add the `[GSERVICEACCOUNT]`.
6. Form the drop down menu `Select a role`, select the `Storage Admin` role.
7. Click on `Save`.

Now if you execute again the `node [FILE_NAME].js`. You should see all the buckets listed on your Cloud Shell.